# Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String[] with ResultView

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm writing a code using vosk ( for offline speech recognition), in my string.xml i wrote a string-array:

```
 <string-array name="say_something">
        <item >Say  : Zero</item>
        <item >Say  : One</item>
        <item >Say  : two</item>
        <item >Say  : three</item>
        <item >Say  : four</item>
        <item >Say  : five</item>
        <item >Say  : six</item>
        <item >Say  : seven</item>
        <item >Say  : eight</item>
        <item >Say  : nine</item>
        <item >Say  : ten</item>
        <item >Say  : Blue</item>
        <item >Say  : Red</item>
        <item >Say  : white</item>
        <item >Say  : Black</item>
        <item >Say  : Green</item>
        <item >Say  : Yellow</item>
        <item >Say  : Pink</item>
        <item >Say  : Grey</item>
        <item >Say  : Purple</item>

    </string-array>
```

and in my java code i tried getting the text value using ResultView as the following:

```
case STATE_MIC:
                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.recognize_mic)).setText(R.string.stop_microphone);
                for(i=0;i<21; i++) {
                    resultView.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.say_something));
                    findViewById(R.id.recognize_file).setEnabled(false);
                    findViewById(R.id.recognize_mic).setEnabled(true);
                    findViewById(R.id.pause).setEnabled((true));
                 }
                break;
```

and i get the error:

```
add method contract to getResources
```

and i also get the error :

```
Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String[]
```

What should i do please help me.
ps: the State mic is int :

```
static private final int STATE_MIC = 4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to put the array in settext("") function
it's not possible by syntax, We can only pass string value in Settext finction

try this

```
String [] saySome = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.say_something);
String temp = "";
for(String item:saySome){
  temp+=item+"\n";
}

resultView.setText(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us go through your code, specifically this block

```java
case STATE_MIC:
                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.recognize_mic)).setText(R.string.stop_microphone);
                for(i=0;i<21; i++) {
                    resultView.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.say_something));
                    findViewById(R.id.recognize_file).setEnabled(false);
                    findViewById(R.id.recognize_mic).setEnabled(true);
                    findViewById(R.id.pause).setEnabled((true));
                 }
                break;
```

Here you are setting the text as follows

```java
resultView.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.say_something));
```

But the thing is you getting an array from resources, what you need to supply is a single string. You cannot assign a complete array. Either you need to combine that array to a single string and then assign it or assign a single element of that array as follows

```java
resultView.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.say_something)[0]);
```

Comment: ok so i just did as you told me and there is no error, but sadly when i executed it , the app stops suddenly :( (Unfortunatly , Vosk Demo has stopped)

Comment: Are you using `getResources` in a non-activity or Fragment class?

Comment: no, i'm writing this code in the 'VoskActivity' file

Answer (score 0):

Initialse array :

```
String [] saySomething = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.say_something);
```

and in for loop

```
resultView.setText(saySomething[i]);
```

Comment: thank you but it's same as @che10 it takes out the error but when i executed it , the app stops suddenly  (Unfortunatly , Vosk Demo has stopped)